# Is it necessary to save individual items of Entity using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am learning hibernate and came to know it is an ORM tool.

## Consider this scenario:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_DETAILS")
public class UserInfo {

    @ElementCollection
    Set<Address> addressList = new HashSet<Address>();

    // Some other code...
}
```

## Main application:

```
public class MainApp {

     public static void main(String s[]) {

         SessionFactory sf = null;
         sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(); // This will read the hibernate.cfg.xml file

          // We can save using session.save(object)
     }
}
```

As can be seen from the code, we have a `addressList` (Collection) in the `UserInfo` entity.

## My question is:

When we save the entity, would the `embedded object` be automatically saved as part of the entity or we need to specifically save the `collection object` as well?

Comment: Assuming your factory save method would consume UserInfo, no you don't have to specifically save the collection object, as long as it's set in UserInfo object.

Comment: you need to specify the `Cascade` strategy to persist the child entities

Comment: @Saravana: They aren't child entity, it is Collection. Where do we specify this? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @CuriousMind `ElementCollection` is for `basic` types and `Embeddable` types. Is `Address` Embeddable? If no you need to change it to `OneToMany`, and specify `Cascade` type

Comment: @Saravana: In my case `Address` isn't Entity, it is `Embeddable` and in `UserInfo` a collection is created.

Comment: why do you want to do like that? It should be `OneToMany` relationship right?

Comment: @Saravana: I am trying to learn how Hibernate behaves in different scenarios. I agree in real case, it can be 1:1 relationship as you described. However, in my case, does it get stored automatically when we store the `UserInfo` object?

Answer (score 0):

1. cascade="none", the default, tells Hibernate to ignore the association.
2. cascade="save-update" tells Hibernate to navigate the association when the
   transaction is committed and when an object is passed to save() or
   update() and save newly instantiated transient instances and persist changes to
   detached instances.
3. cascade="delete" tells Hibernate to navigate the association and delete persistent instances when an object is passed to delete().
4. cascade="all" means to cascade both save-update and delete, as well as
   calls to evict and lock.
5. cascade="all-delete-orphan" means the same as cascade="all" but, in addition,
   Hibernate deletes any persistent entity instance that has been removed
   (dereferenced) from the association (for example, from a collection).
6. cascade="delete-orphan" Hibernate will delete any persistent entity
   instance that has been removed (dereferenced) from the association (for
   example, from a collection).

Comment: as per your mapping file , when you save UserInfo it will save address details as well.